# Ajax request not showing in my django template even though getting json from request

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to display search result for Youtube videos while user are typing their search terms. 
I am using Django, jquery and ajax.

Here are the important information from my different files (I am just showing the relevant info and cutting the other stuff) :

-> Urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = [
path('video/search/', views.video_search, name="video_search"),]
```

-> add_video.html file :

```
<form method="post">
    {% for field in search_form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>

<div id="search_result"></div>
```

-> forms.py file :

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
search_term = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="Search for videos")
```

-> firstajax.js file :

```
$(function() {
var DelayTimer;
$('#id_search_term').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(DelayTimer);
    $('#search_result').text('Loading...');
    DelayTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var text = $('#id_search_term').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'video/search/',
            data: {
                'search_term': text
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var results = '';
                $('#search_result').text('');
                data['items'].forEach(function(video){
                    results += video['snippet']['title']
                });
                $('#search_result').append(results);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

});

-> views.py file :

```
def video_search(request):
search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
if search_form.is_valid():
    encoded_search_term = parse.quote(search_form.cleaned_data["search_term"])
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q={encoded_search_term}&key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}')
    return JsonResponse(response.json())
return JsonResponse({'error': 'Not able to validate form'})
```

---

Whenever I am typing in my search bar, I get just the "Loading" displaying in search_result div... And nothing else is happening. However, I get an HTTP 200 as response for my request and when I go and check the (local host)video/search/?search_term=mysearchterms, I can see the json I want like that :

```
{"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse", "etag": "B7bvQKmH1RYz_vKyhrqSeOp8_Y4", "nextPageToken": "CAYQAA", "regionCode": "FR", "pageInfo": {"totalResults": 1000000, "resultsPerPage": 6}, "items": [{"kind": "youtube#searchResult", "etag": "JbFNoD-7t_z8DeR3uysPXKr7RwE", "id": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "xPwa6NR37Ds"}, "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2020-05-11T21:01:17Z", "channelId": "UCiYcA0gJzg855iSKMrX3oHg", "title": "THE BEST SPOOKY SCARY SUNDAY SO FAR | Reacting To Scary Videos [SSS #023]", "description": "Can this REALLY be!? A #SpookyScarySunday with a perfect rating of 10/10? PLEASE check out more works from the ANIMATORS: Railroad (MeatCanyon): ...", "thumbnails": {"default": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xPwa6NR37Ds/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90}, "medium": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xPwa6NR37Ds/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180}, "high": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xPwa6NR37Ds/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360}}, "channelTitle": "CoryxKenshin", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "publishTime": "2020-05-11T21:01:17Z"}}, {"kind": "youtube#searchResult", "etag": "SVAGxv49Pbc2yFVKX0O7Hqp5tZQ", "id": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "JHeU7IclczY"}, "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2020-05-10T19:11:35Z", "channelId": "UCiYcA0gJzg855iSKMrX3oHg", "title": "DO NOT TAKE YOUR EYES OFF HIM | Reacting To Scary Videos [SSS #022]", "description": "For this #SpookyScarySunday episode, I compiled some old clips that have never 'officially' made it into an #SSS entry but as I am short on time HERE THEY ...", "thumbnails": {"default": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JHeU7IclczY/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90}, "medium": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JHeU7IclczY/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180}, "high": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JHeU7IclczY/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360}}, "channelTitle": "CoryxKenshin", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "publishTime": "2020-05-10T19:11:35Z"}}, {"kind": "youtube#searchResult", "etag": "Aw_CoF2Ep36gJuCBUFAT1huUqOE", "id": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "94zbEIlTHGI"}, "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2020-05-03T23:55:09Z", "channelId": "UCiYcA0gJzg855iSKMrX3oHg", "title": "THE ORIGIN OF SIREN HEAD | Reacting To Scary Videos [SSS #021]", "description": "Another week of #SpookyScarySunday with a HEAVY emphasis on the up and coming Creepypasta monster, SIREN HEAD. PLEASE check out more works ...", "thumbnails": {"default": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/94zbEIlTHGI/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90}, "medium": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/94zbEIlTHGI/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180}, "high": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/94zbEIlTHGI/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360}}, "channelTitle": "CoryxKenshin", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "publishTime": "2020-05-03T23:55:09Z"}}, {"kind": "youtube#searchResult", "etag": "g1iEghTkqsu2DgxnposRwixYQNY", "id": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "ZQddjrlIjFo"}, "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2020-05-15T10:03:39Z", "channelId": "UCKzoPVx8qo1A2G_xpQpX2Yg", "title": "MGA KATANUNGAN TUNGKOL SA SSS SBWS PROGRAM | E-LEARNING | iSirMac", "description": "SSS Official Facebook Page: https://www.facebook.com/SSSPh/ PLS. SUBSCRIBE TO MY 2ND CHANNEL: ...", "thumbnails": {"default": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZQddjrlIjFo/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90}, "medium": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZQddjrlIjFo/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180}, "high": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZQddjrlIjFo/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360}}, "channelTitle": "iSirMac", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "publishTime": "2020-05-15T10:03:39Z"}}, {"kind": "youtube#searchResult", "etag": "2XMimglxgRxl9cIgm6IzDAbjzzc", "id": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "dzrKV_ceVKs"}, "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2020-04-16T18:38:03Z", "channelId": "UCKHb_N_Zq0uv0_EYOiDhhgA", "title": "SSS 5K TO 8K NA AYUDA O TULONG PINANSIYAL SIMULA APRIL 16, 2020 | ALAMIN! | SOCIAL SECURITY SYSTEM", "description": "Unemployment Benefit kay SSS Pwedeng Makakuha ng Hanggang 20k Eto po Guideline kung Paano: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aztXcndZIMw Sa mga ...", "thumbnails": {"default": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dzrKV_ceVKs/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90}, "medium": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dzrKV_ceVKs/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180}, "high": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dzrKV_ceVKs/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360}}, "channelTitle": "SuperMark TV", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "publishTime": "2020-04-16T18:38:03Z"}}, {"kind": "youtube#searchResult", "etag": "4HzuPEryfra2aXgiWOZ00DoSdic", "id": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "edk2uac_x0Y"}, "snippet": {"publishedAt": "2020-04-19T18:21:52Z", "channelId": "UCiYcA0gJzg855iSKMrX3oHg", "title": "SPOOKY SCARY SUNDAY IS BACK | Reacting To Scary Stories [SSS #019]", "description": "The FIRST #SpookyScarySunday in a year and you guys BROUGHT THE HEAT!! PLEASE check out more works from the ANIMATORS: Golden Arches ...", "thumbnails": {"default": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/edk2uac_x0Y/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90}, "medium": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/edk2uac_x0Y/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180}, "high": {"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/edk2uac_x0Y/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360}}, "channelTitle": "CoryxKenshin", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "publishTime": "2020-04-19T18:21:52Z"}}]}
```

It is weird because when I tried to check if the Ajax call was working it seems ok and also when I check with something easier like this : 
-> views.py file:

```
def video_search(request):
search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
if search_form.is_valid():
    response = search_form.cleaned_data['search_term']
    return JsonResponse({"Hello":response})
return JsonResponse({'error':'Not able to validate form'})
```

-> firstajax.js file:

```
$(function() {
var DelayTimer;
$('#id_search_term').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(DelayTimer);
    $('#search_result').text('Loading...');
    DelayTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var text = $('#id_search_term').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'video/search/',
            data: {
                'search_term': text
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#search_result').text(data['Hello']);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

});

Then it works just fine and the "Loading..." text within my search_result div is replaced with the search term that I started typing as a user.

Any idea what is going wrong please ?
Thanks a lot for any help :) 
T.

Comment: Hey Tristan, how about replacing  results += video['snippet']['title'] with $('#search_result').append(video['snippet']['title']);  and remove this "$('#search_result').append(results);" from the file ? Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vinay ! 
Unfortunately same problem happening... 
The loading text stays up whatever I am typing. 
I feel like the ajax is not even going to the success code as the loading is not disappearing to be replace with nothing with $('#search_result').text('');

Comment: It finally worked :D 
Apparently ajax was maybe not happy with the success url... from url: 'video/search/', to url: '/video/search/' and probably the change in code that you suggested but I still dont understand why my results += video['snippet']['title'] and then $('#search_result').append(results); was not working.